# Android - Displaying WiFi RSSI after pressing a button

Tags: android, wifi, rssi

I'm trying to make a really simple application that would simply have a button and textview, where the texview displays the RSSI value from the wifi connected.

I made this code so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView level;
    WifiInfo wifiInfo;
    WifiManager wifiManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        level = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.levelText);

    }

    int linkSpeed = 100; //My default textview is O

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        linkSpeed = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getRssi();

    }

    public void clickButton(View view) {
        level.setText(""+linkSpeed);
    }
```

However, when I click the button, the textview changes from 0 (default value) to 100. I believe the level value should be equal to the RSSI but it doesn't work.
Could somebody explain me what I did wrong ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: what makes you think `onReceive` will be called?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, I really didn't have good a good understanding of the functions (I thought onReceive was called like onCreate). Here's my code now for anyone interested:

```
public class WiFiActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Variables
    private static final String TAG = WiFiActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private int value; // RSSI value
    private TextView textRSSI;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wi_fi);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        Log.i(TAG, "Test");
        textRSSI = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextRSSI);

        //initializeWiFiListener();
    }

    public void myClickHandler(View view) {
        initializeWiFiListener();
    }

    private void initializeWiFiListener(){
        Log.i(TAG, "executing initializeWiFiListener");

        String connectivity_context = Context.WIFI_SERVICE;
        final WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(connectivity_context);

        if(!wifi.isWifiEnabled()){
            if(wifi.getWifiState() != WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING){
                wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
                value = info.getRssi();
                Log.i(TAG, Integer.toString(value));

                if(value <= -30 && value > -67) // Amazing
                    textRSSI.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                else if(value <= -67 && value > -70) // Very good
                    textRSSI.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                else if(value <= -70 && value > -80) // Okay
                    textRSSI.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                else if(value <= -80 && value > -90) // Not good
                    textRSSI.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                else if(value <= -90) // Unusable
                    textRSSI.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                textRSSI.setText(""+value);
            }

        }, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION));
    }
```